# Pyserial objects in a for loop

Tags: python, object, for-loop, pyserial

I open 4 serial ports with this method:

```
ComPorts = ['com11','com13','com7','com19']
stimeout = 0.000120   ## 120 us character timeout
baud = 115200 
serList = {}
set_key = 0x0E 
keyList = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for idx,com in enumerate(ComPorts):  ## open up the COM ports
    serList[idx] = serial.Serial(com,baud,timeout=stimeout)
```

I want to write a common message to all ports - this fails:

```
for ser in serList:  
    SER_tx_command(ser,set_key,keyList) # send'
```

But this works (less pythonic):

```
for idx in range(len(ComPorts)): 
    SER_tx_command(serList[idx],set_key,keyList) # send
```

It is giving error in this common function:

```
def SER_tx_command(ser,cmd,payload):
    length = len(payload)+4;
    cksum = (0x01 + length + cmd)&0x00FF
    msg = [0x01,length,cmd]
    if (length > 4):
        for val in payload:
            cksum = (cksum+val)&0x00FF
            msg.extend([val])
    msg.extend([cksum])
    for val in msg:
        ser.write(chr(val))  ###  ERROR HERE  ###
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packet_test02.py", line 468, in <module>
    update_key(key_jump)
  File "packet_test02.py", line 149, in update_key
    SER_tx_command(ser,set_key,keyList) # send the packet msg
  File "packet_test02.py", line 28, in SER_tx_command
    ser.write(chr(val))
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'
```

How can I make the loop iterate over the serial port objects?
Or is that not possible with python, I must use index iterator method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`serList` is a `dict` not a `list` and iterating a `dict` iterates its keys. In your case, the keys are the integer indexes from `enumerate`. You could iterate its values instead (and rename the variable to make it less confusing)

```
for ser in serDict.values():  
    SER_tx_command(ser, set_key, keyList) # send'
```

or use a `list` instead of a `dict`

```
ComPorts = ['com11','com13','com7','com19']
stimeout = 0.000120   ## 120 us character timeout
baud = 115200 
set_key = 0x0E 
keyList = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

serList = [serial.Serial(com,baud,timeout=stimeout) for com in ComPorts]  ## 
for ser in serList:  
    SER_tx_command(ser, set_key, keyList) # send'
```

Comment: This makes sense - will use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ser in serList:
```

iterates over the keys in the `serList` dictionary. In your case the keys are integers, not Serial objects.

Try:

```
for ser in serList:  
    SER_tx_command(serList[ser],set_key,keyList) # send'
```

Comment: That's what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: This does work, but the tdelaney post below is what I will likely use.  Thanks!